# Decompiling jas/ClassEnv created .class files from inside a Java application

Tags: java, decompiling

My java application creates .class files using jas ClassEnv.  I need to be able to decompile these .class files and turn the contents into a string (so that it can be displayed in TextArea).  All of the decompilers I have found are standalone programs, are there any integrated java libraries that can do this decompilation?  Or Is there anyway I can get a string representation from the ClasseEnv object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some options I found:

1. [back2code](http://code.google.com/p/back2code/)
2. [Soot](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) + [Dava](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/dava/)
3. [jclazz](http://jclazz.sourceforge.net/)
4. [jdec](http://jdec.sourceforge.net/)
5. [jode](http://jode.sourceforge.net/)
6. [dcompiler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dcompiler/)
7. [jreversepro](http://jreversepro.blogspot.com/)

*Note*: I have not used any of the above myself, so you will have to check if they support features you require, or if they are mature enough for your needs

*Note*: although some of the listed options are seemingly standalone programs, all that require Java to be executed (that is, you are not running an .exe for example -- but *do* check inside .bat/.sh scripts), you can invoke from your program: just add the appropriate .jar files to your application's classpath and you can access all the classes in them from within your program -- at the minimum you will be able to call the `main()` method in the default class of the .jar with the appropriate parameters.  You might need to open a file (where the source of the decompiled .class is extracted) to access the source as a string in your program.